# Is there a way to combine 2 measurements into a new measurement in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I have 2 measurements:

Every person's hourly location data:
`location_data={ssn, name, location}`

and

every location's hourly temperature data:
`temperature_data={location, temperature}`

Now, I want to combine these 2 measurements based upon location and create a new measurement that has full information:

`location_temperature_history={ssn, name, location, temperature}`

Is it possible to do so using continuous query?